# String Dict to Unicode conversion

Tags: python, dictionary, utf-8, python-unicode

I was wondering if there are any intuit functionality that I can use to go from string dict to unicode dict.

Input:

```
{'name': 'Lexus', 'model': 'GS F'}
```

Expected output:

```
{u'name': u'Lexus', u'model': u'GS F'}
```

Comment: Do you know how to go from `str` to `unicode`?

Comment: unicode(inputString, "utf-8")

Comment: If this is literally in source code, don't do it at runtime!  Use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.

Comment: If you are new to python, I suggest you start with Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> d={'name': 'Lexus', 'model': 'GS F'}
>>> d={k.decode('utf8'): v.decode('utf8') for k, v in d.items()}
```

output :

```
{u'model': u'GS F', u'name': u'Lexus'}
```